# Gradle - jar file name in java plugin

Tags: gradle

I am trying with Gradle first time. I am trying with a maven java project to compile and create a jar file. It is compiling and creating the jar file in build/libs directory as

> **trunk**-XXXVERSION-SNAPSHOT.jar

I am running gradle build file from trunk directory of this maven java project.

I want to get the project name (for ex: project1) in the jar file name, something like

> **project1**-XXXVERSION-SNAPSHOT.jar

in build/libs directory.
Please suggest.

Comment: Note, if you use **Spring Boot** you might want to [mind the `bootJar` task instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55427009/1850609).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The default project name is taken from the directory the project is stored in. Instead of changing the naming of the jar explicitly you should set the project name correct for your build. At the moment this is not possible within the `build.gradle` file. Instead, you have to create a `settings.gradle` file in your root directory. This `settings.gradle` file should have this one liner included:

```
rootProject.name = 'project1'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. It worked for me. Also found that we can use 'doFirst' for jar and it worked too. So what is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: what do you mean with "we can use doFirst for jar" ? jar is a "normal" gradle task, that can be augmented with custom action closures via doLast and doFirst.

Comment: using this snippet makes also sure, that your other zips, maven archives etc have the correct naming as they all depend on your project name

Comment: I was using the doFirst closure, augmenting jar.

Comment: In the most recent version of gradle, this property is read only: Cannot set the value of read-only property 'name' on root project 'root'.

Comment: @koppor project.name is readonly in build.gradle for a very long time.  As mentioned you have to use the settings.gradle file as shown above to change the project name(s).

Comment: This solution works, however you cannot apply it to multi-project/hierarchic setups. The settings.gradle can be only in the root project directory. If you need to change the name of sub projects, you can work with archivesBaseName as stated in the other answer.

Comment: @DaniloTommasina You can specify the names of your projects in your single `settings.gradle` file, for both the root project and each subproject.

Answer (score 132):

Here is the directory structure:

```
trunk
˪ build
  ˪ libs
    ˪ project1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
˪ build.gradle
```

Include the following in `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

archivesBaseName = 'project1'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
group = 'example'
```

This will produce the correct ZIPs, POMs and JARs.

---

Additionally, try setting:

```
archivesBaseName = 'project1'
```

or (deprecated):

```
jar.baseName = 'project1'
```

Comment: Just to keep the discussion complete: the first version does work and it also produces correct zips, maven archives and so on. I find it also more elegant. I will edit my answer to provide full script.

Comment: Yes, this works too, but I do not see the POMs and JARs generated in the repository. I am using 'uploadArchives' to publish it to maven artifactory after declaring 'repositories'.

Comment: archivesBaseName works but jar.baseName can be problematic as your sources jar might not be named correctly.

Comment: baseName was deprecated (Gradle 6.2): https://docs.gradle.org/6.2.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html
It was replaced by archivesBaseName.

Comment: in kotlin, the archiveBaseName is `project.base.archivesBaseName`, as of gradle 6.2

Comment: In Gradle 6.6.1, it's `jar.baseName('nameString')`.

Comment: jar.baseName is worked on .jar but not for javadoc. Use archivesBaseName.

Answer (score 29):

I recently migrated to gradle 4.6 (from 3. something) and the

```
jar {
    baseName = 'myjarname'
}
```

stopped working, gradle named my jar from the folder name.

So I switched to `archivesBaseName = 'myjarname'` which works.

Maybe this helps somebody else too.

Answer (score 18):

In Kotlin DSL you can also use:

```kotlin
tasks.jar {
    archiveFileName.set("app.jar")
}
```

With Spring boot and Kotlin DSL you can use:

```kotlin
tasks {
    bootJar {
        archiveFileName.set("app.jar")
    }
}
```

Comment: On Spring Boot add this to end of `build.gradle` but does not work.

Comment: At least in the Kotlin DSL this works. I have adapted the solution.

Answer (score 16):

If you has some submobule, you can use in build.gradle (for jar)

```
configurations {
    jar.archiveName = 'submodule-jar.jar'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using a newer Gradle version, `baseName`, `archiveName` will now be deprecated. Instead, use something like

```
jar {
   archivesBaseName = 'project1'
   archiveVersion = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Comment: AFAIK it's `archiveBaseName` not `archive*s*BaseName`.

Comment: yes it's archivesBaseName = 'project1' with an s.  This sets the jar base name in the case where it builds multiple jars in lib folder.  Such as when you build the ueber jar.

Answer (score 4):

Currently using Kotlin as Gradle DSL. Following statement works for me:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<AbstractArchiveTask> {
    setProperty("archiveFileName", "hello-world.jar")
}
```

It works on Spring Boot executable jars as well.

If you want to keep version numbers:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<AbstractArchiveTask> {
    setProperty("archiveBaseName", "hello-world")
}
```

It will produce something like `hello-world-1.2.3.jar`

Comment: This solution has the advantage that the changed name also applies to the source jar.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to append a date to the jar file name, you can do it like this:

```
jar {
    baseName +='_' +new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyyy").format(new java.util.Date())
    println(baseName) // just to verify
```

which results in `<basename>_07_05_2020.jar`

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the 'version' tag in your build.gradle file!

Comment: Default gradle behavior is to add the `version` parameter to artifact name when run sending it like this:

`./gradlew build -Pversion=${APPLICATION_VERSION}`


In this case `APPLICATION_VERSION` can be generated in the bash script, for instance getting the last tag from `git`

Answer (score 2):

It can works in Gradle 7.5.1 with Groove DSL:

```
jar {
    archiveFileName = "name.jar"
}
```

If you are using Kotlin DSL:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<Jar> {
    archiveFileName.set("name.jar")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add the following:

```
tasks.bootJar {
    archiveFileName.set("file-name-here.jar")
}
```

(Gradle 7.6.1, Spring Boot 3.0.6 and the Gradle Kotlin DSL)