# Gradle - Change the name of the jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I would like to change the name of the jar when I do a

```
./gradlew clean assemble
```

The name of my jar is `my-awsome-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and I want to generate `my-awsome-app.jar`.

I tested to do this in the `build.gradle`:

```
configurations {
   jar.archiveName = "my-awsome-app.${jar.extension}"
}
```

...but this is not working, the name is still the same

Comment: This is what I have done and that is not working

Comment: Look at the link I posted, there's multiple answers in the post.

Comment: Sorry about the closing, I didn't notice the [spring-boot] tag before.

Answer (score 10):

Since you are using **Spring Boot**, you should use the `bootJar` task instead (notice [`bootJar`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/gradle/tasks/bundling/BootJar.java) extends `Jar`).

Since [`archiveName` in `Jar`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveName) has been deprecated, use [`archiveFileName`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar:archiveFileName):

```
bootJar {
   archiveFileName = 'my-awesome-app.jar'
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution when you need build version for the Jenkins pipeline and artifact but not the JAR name